# How to create document features from word-vectors?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, feature-extraction, word2vec

I have around 100000 documents of varying word length. I also have trained a word2vec model on the entire corpus. Now how do I go from having this word-vectors to create features of same dimension for each individual documents?

I am aware of a couple of techniques of how this can be done, one is to take simple average of vectors of all the words in the document and another is to do k-means clustering.

Can you suggest some other way of carrying out this task?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a vector for each document, you might want to check Doc2Vec.

[Doc2Vec - Gensim Tutorial](http://rare-technologies.com/doc2vec-tutorial)

[Doc2Vec paper](https://cs.stanford.edu/~quocle/paragraph_vector.pdf)